# Update mysql Table from PL SQL error ORA-28536: error in processing Heterogeneous Services initialization parameters

Tags: mysql, oracle, heterogeneous-services

UPDATE query without WHERE clause working fine. But when i use WHERE clause then it shows error

> ORA-28536: error in processing Heterogeneous Services initialization parameters
>   ORA-28507: error in data dictionary view sys.hs$_class_init
>   ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from MYSQL_ATULSSO
>   ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
>   ORA-02067: transaction or savepoint rollback required
>   ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
>   ORA-02067: transaction or savepoint rollback required.

My code :

```
DECLARE
  A NUMBER(15) := 70;
  B NUMBER(15) := 69;
BEGIN
  UPDATE ATL1_SSO_ACCESS_REQ_DETAILS A SET A.REQ_ID = B;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('done11');
  UPDATE ATL1_SSO_ACCESS_REQ_DETAILS A SET A.REQ_ID = B WHERE A.REQ_ID = A;
  COMMIT;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('done');

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('not done1');
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Output: 
done1
not done

Comment: So, are you using Heterogeneous Services (to connect to a MySQL database?)? Is ATL1_SSO_ACCESS_REQ_DETAILS a table on the remote database? Have you verified the installation of the data dictionary view `sys.hs$_class_init`???

Comment: ATL1_SSO_ACCESS_REQ_DETAILS is synonym created in oracle.
CREATE SYNONYM "ATL1_SSO_ACCESS_REQ_DETAILS" FOR "atl_sso"."ATL_SSO_ACCESS_REQ_DETAILS"@"MYSQL_ATULSSO.ATUL.CO.IN";

I have no idea about heterogeneous services. 

SELECT * FROM sys.hs$_class_init; this query return nothing.

Comment: Heterogeneous Services is an Oracle product for connecting non-Oracle databases such as MySQL with Oracle databases. This is what you're trying to do but there seems to be a problem with your HS configuration. You need to talk to your DBA to get this sorted out.

Comment: Can you help me out to get HS configuration?

Comment: Sorry, no. I know enough about HS to recognise when it's in use, but I've never worked with it myself. This requires knowledge of your infrastructure. Is there really nobody in your organisation you can ask to help you?

Comment: I think commit is the one causing the issue, check with your dba how to implement commit in a heterogeneous configuration

Comment: @psaraj12 No. Commit is not causing the issue, flow goes to exception at UPDATE query. and the error is 
[MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld - 5.5.16] Unknown Column 'atl_sso.ATL_SSO_ACCESS_REQ_DETAILS.REQ_ID' in 'where clause' {42S22, NativeErr = 1054}
ORA 02063 : preceding 2 lines from MYSQL_ATLSSO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer.
You can update from Database Link. Below is syntax

```
UPDATE "*DB_NAME*"."*TABLE_NAME*"@"*DB_LINK*"
SET "*DB_NAME*"."*TABLE_NAME*"."*COLUMN_NAME*"@"*DB_LINK*"= 'r2' 
WHERE "*DB_NAME*"."*TABLE_NAME*"."*COLUMN_NAME*"@"*DB_LINK*"='r1';
```

example:

```
UPDATE "atul_sso"."ATL_SSO_ACCESS_REQ_DETAILS"@"mysql_atulsso.atul.co.in"
SET "atul_sso"."ATL_SSO_ACCESS_REQ_DETAILS"."REQ_TYPE"@"mysql_atulsso.atul.co.in"= 'r2' 
WHERE "atul_sso"."ATL_SSO_ACCESS_REQ_DETAILS"."REQ_TYPE"@"mysql_atulsso.atul.co.in"='r1';
```

I still have one more doubt. I can not update using Synonym. is there any syntax for it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think using table alias A in where clause may be the issue
Try the below code

```
DECLARE
A NUMBER(15) := 70;
B NUMBER(15) := 69;
BEGIN
 UPDATE ATL1_SSO_ACCESS_REQ_DETAILS A SET 
 A.REQ_ID = B;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('done11');
  UPDATE ATL1_SSO_ACCESS_REQ_DETAILS A SET 
  A.REQ_ID = B WHERE A.REQ_ID = 70;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('done');

  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('not done1');
   END;
```

Comment: No Alias is not causing issue . I tried without aliasing also.
I tried almost all possible ways, used '(single inverted comma), "(Double inverted comma), `(back tic) .